# Disabling/Removing Razor Engine Template Cache

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I'm currently testing out the formatting of some emails that uses the RazorEngine parsing for our emails that are stored in Razor files. I've noticed through several blogs though that there can be a serious performance hit using this and is recommended to take use of their template caching system.

However, when testing out the modifications I make to the Razor files, the changes don't come through due to the caching implemented. Does anyone have a simple solution to clearing/disabling the template caches.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: As far as I can see, disabling cache is not an option... the only thing I can see in the documentation, is to write your own CustomCacheProvider (something like NoCacheProvider) and do not cache anything [see here](http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateManager.html)... but personally I would not do this. In my opinion it would have been nice if caching could have been turned On/Off.